# Using Raw Queries in a Sails App using Sequelize as ORM

Tags: sql, node.js, sails.js, sequelize.js

I am working with a sails application that uses Sequelize as the ORM tool. Initial integration between the app and Sequelize was established via the sails-hook-sequelize plugin which can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-sequelize). This approach has worked great so far, no problem defining and using models.

However, I hit a road block when I wanted to define a View as a Sequelize object. Sequelize doesn't (yet) have an easy way to do this. The work around I found was to execute a raw query and populate a table with the result.

Now I come to the second road block and the actual question itself. How do I simply execute a sequelize.query inside of my sails application? In stand alone node apps using sequelize I don't have a problem. However, this sails application has gotten away from me to the point where I'm not sure what object to actually call .query from! What I'm looking for is something simple like

```
Sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM `Document.MyView`", { type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
```

Sadly the above gives me `sequelize.query is not a function`

I have a connections.coffee file where the database connection is defined. It is named 'Core', however when I try `Core.query` I get `Core is undefined`

Seems like I am missing something simple and fundamental from stacking too many things on top of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright my problems arose from the sails-hook-sequelize plugin. Luckily my answer came from that plugin as well!

"sequelize" is a global in this plugin. So don't add a `sequelize = require 'sequelize'`.
simply call the raw query with sequelize.query as expected (case sensitive).

Then your raw query should work! Thanks from past me.

Comment: when I've tried calling sequelize.query(myRawQueryString) in my controller I happened to get error `ReferenceError: sequelize is not defined`. How could it be possible when sequelize is a global object. Please help.